# Autofillable Formula to transpose sum of row data into a columns

Tags: excel

Is there an excel formula that sums quarterly row data and transposes it into a column data? Being able to autofill right would be a plus. Thanks

[Please see the attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWkmX.png)

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:
[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT((ROUNDUP(MONTH($A$2:$A$13)/3,0)=VALUE(RIGHT(F1,1)))*$B$2:$B$13)`

**EDIT:**

Sorry I didn't notice your cut off period was offset, try:

[image]

`=SUMPRODUCT((ROUNDUP((MOD(MONTH($A$2:$A$13)+1,12)+1)/3,0)=VALUE(RIGHT(F1,1)))*$B$2:$B$13)`

Comment: fwiw, the worksheet's RIGHT and LEFT functions default to 1 character so `RIGHT(F1)` is the same as `RIGHT(F1, 1)`.

Comment: @J.Doe thanks for your help. Was wondering if the formula can be modified to extend to 2013/14 and beyond.